# How to assign default value to DropdownButtonFormField in fltuter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to assign the default value to the DropdownButtonFormField in a flutter. I am trying to edit the record but I am not able to assign the default value to it.

I have workersList as a  `List`.

```
 DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                    value: workersList[0]['worker_name'],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Payment To",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.phone_android,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null) {
                        return "Please Select Worker";
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    hint: const Text('Select Worker'),
                    items: workersList.map((Map value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value['worker_id'].toString(),
                        child: Text(value['worker_name']),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      _workerController.text = value.toString();
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the `value` property of the `DropDownMenuItem` to `['worker_id']`, you need to set the initial value like:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  value: workersList[0]['worker_id'],
  ...
)
```

Comment: `There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Breakfast Expenses. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
package:flutter/…/material/dropdown.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1568 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'` Getting This error sir...

Comment: Please edit your question and add `workersList` data and also your current complete code to find out what's wrong.

Comment: initially workers list is emtpy but after initState I add values to the workerList List.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same property that you used for DropDownMenuItem as a value, So just change the value

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  value: workersList[0]['worker_name'],
  ...
)
```

to

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  value: workersList[0]['worker_id'].toString(),
  ...
)
```

Comment: `There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Breakfast Expenses. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
package:flutter/…/material/dropdown.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1568 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'` Getting This error sir...

Comment: could you please add your code to see what the wrong exactly